# Как поменять толщину текста при клике на кнопку и обратно JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

```js
$('#typeBold').click(function() {
  $('#textBlock').css('fontWeight', '900');
});
```

```html
<button id="typeBold" class="btn btn-light left">Edit</button>
<div id="textBlock" class="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку текст в блоке становился жирным и при повторном клике на неё он становился нормальной толщины.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#typeBold').click(function() {
  $('#textBlock').toggleClass('bold');
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="typeBold" class="btn btn-light left">Edit</button>
<div id="textBlock" class="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

И тут я бы хотел задать вопрос, зачем тут вообще JavaScript и темболее jQuery ?

HTML

```
<label for="check1">Кнопка</label>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox">
<div>This text must be bold?</div>
```

и немного стилей CSS

```
#check1 { display: none; }
#check1:checked + div { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

Comment: Иногда бывает легче написать простенький скрипт, чем усложнять HTML и добавлять новые классы)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.js-typeBold').on('click', function() {
  var type = (this.clicked = !this.clicked) ? "900" : "100";
  $(this).next().css('font-weight', type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="js-typeBold btn btn-light left">Edit</button>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>

<button class="js-typeBold btn btn-light left">Edit</button>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

`var type = (this.clicked = !this.clicked) ? "900" : "100";` — называется "тернарный оператор". Если результат выражения в скобках будет true, в переменную type запишется строка "900", иначе - "100". `this` ссылается на объект, в контексте которого была вызвана функция (кликнутая кнопка). Изначально в объекте кнопки нет свойства `clicked`, поэтому this.clicked - undefined, но сразу же происходит присваивание: `this.clicked = !this.clicked` как-бы → `this.clicked = !undefined`. Это логическое `!` "НЕ". А undefined в логическом контексте будет false. `!false` становится `true` и присваивается в this.clicked (а операция присваивания возвращает присвоенное значение). Значение выражения true → возьмется "900". На следующем клике this.clicked уже хранит значение true. `!true` → `false`, возьмется "100" и так по кругу)